# Prove that $f$ maps null sets to null sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that there exists $f: [a, b]\to\mathbb{R}^1$, which maps each measurable set $E$ contained in $[a, b]$ onto a measurable set contained in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Prove that for each zero measure set $Z$ contained in $[a, b]$, $f(Z)$ is a zero measure set too.

It's a problem from a real analysis textbook, without any hints. I wondered how "closed interval $[a, b]$" made a difference to this problem, but haven't got any idea.

Comment: Have you encountered the result that every set of positive measure contains an unmeasurable set, yet?

Comment: There is an early theorem in measure theory that says if you have embedded subsets $E_{k+1}\subset E_k$, then the measure of the intersection is equal to the limit of the measures, IF the measure of some $E_k$ is finite.  This is almost certainly the reason you need the compactness of $[a,b]$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Not yet.

Comment: @user219963 Do you mind editing the title into a more _informative_ shape? It's more convenient for searching

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you. I think I can solve it now.

Comment: @user219963: How did I help?

Comment: @CameronBuie According to the result you mentioned before, there exists an unmeasurable set A contained in f(Z)(If m(f(Z))>0). So f^(-1)(A)∩Z⊆ Z is a null set. But f(f^(-1)(A)∩Z)=A is a unmeasurable set, which lead to conflict.

Comment: True enough, but if you haven't encountered that result, yet, you are probably not meant to use it.

Comment: @CameronBuie Of course...It's often the case